How to make a terminal emulator in flask
I want to make a flask app that allows me to run commands in cmd in the path D:
I tried using subprocess and it worked for commands that didn't need to stay open but running something like a file with another flask app or something it would error because it needed it to stay alive or something i also tried os but it spawns a whole cmd hiding my screen, i want the site to look like and act like a regular terminal

You can do something like this:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import threading
import queue

app = Flask(__name__)

output_queue = queue.Queue()

def read_process_output(process):
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if not output:
            break
        output_queue.put(output.decode('utf-8'))

@app.route('/run', methods=['POST'])
def run_command():
    data = request.json
    cmd = data['command']
    cwd = 'D:\\'  # Set the working dir

    process = Popen(cmd, cwd=cwd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE, shell=True, text=True, bufsize=1)
    
    threading.Thread(target=read_process_output, args=(process,), daemon=True).start()

    return jsonify({'status': 'command started'})

@app.route('/output', methods=['GET'])
def get_output():
    try:
        
        line = output_queue.get_nowait()
    except queue.Empty:
        line = None
    return jsonify({'output': line})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

